# Why $\Sigma$ is minimal, if $\frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0} \mathrm{Area}(\Sigma_t)=0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

In this work http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.2883v1.pdf Martin Li claimed that $\Sigma\subset M$ is minimal and $\Sigma$ meets $\partial M$ orthogonally along $\partial \Sigma$ if, only if,

$$0 = \frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0} \mathrm{Area}(\Sigma_t) = - \int_{\Sigma} \langle H, X\rangle da + \int_{\partial \Sigma} \langle  X, \nu\rangle ds,$$

where $\nu$ is the outer conormal vector of $\partial \Sigma$ in  (i.e. the outward unit normal of $\partial \Sigma$ tangent to $\Sigma$), H is the mean curvature vector of  in M and $X$ is the variation field associated with the smooth family $\{\Sigma_t\}$.

So, I not understand because this is clear. Why each term of the right side is zero?

Someone help me? Thak you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read the article but I guess the reason is, 
1. H is zero since $\Sigma$ is minimal, so the first term is 0;
2. X is chosen to be tangent to $\partial{M}$ so it is orthogonal to $\Sigma$, so the second term is 0

Comment: Hi @Xipan Xiao! Actually, he is claimed that it's clear that $\Sigma$ is critical point of area functional if, only if $H=0$ and $\nu \perp \partial M$.